# Problema - Intent para instalar arquivo APK - Android Nougat

Tags: android, apk, android-intent

Pesquisei exaustivamente e não encontrei o problema. Ao tentar instalar um arquivo *APK* usando uma `Intent` no `Android Nougat`, simplesmente não instala e mostra o seguinte aviso: "Ocorreu um problema ao analisar o pacote".

Funciona perfeitamente para abrir arquivos PDF, por exemplo, com ajustes para abrir este tipo de arquivo (`.PDF`). Porém para instalar arquivos .*APK* não funciona.

No `LogCat` não apresenta nenhum erro e com isto não consigo chegar a nenhuma solução.

O que pode estar errado?

Segue código:

*Manifest*:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="br.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

xml/filepaths:

```
<files-path name="storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
```

Código:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "app-debug.apk");
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);

        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app-debug.apk");

        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Por favor, o que pode estar errado neste código? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Parece que a minSdkVersion não é compatível com o celular

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, porem poderias ser um pouco mais especifico?  Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Ao compilar uma uma app você informa qual a API minima necessária para roda-la. Por exemplo: o android 5.0 roda a API 21. Se você criar uma app com a informação na minSdkVersion = 22 e tentar instala-la em um aparelho cuja versão do Android é 5.0 você pode receber esse erro: "Ocorreu um problema ao analisar o pacote", ou seja, analisou o pacote a ser instalado e conclui que é incompatível.

Comment: Ola Reginaldo.  Estou compilando na API 25, no Android Nougat.  Como mencionei também, na mesma aplicação uso um Intent pra abrir arquivos em PDF, utilizando FileProvider, direcionado à dispositivos com API 24 ou superior e funciona normalmente.  A questão é executar o arquivo com extensão APK.